# Firefox CORS blocking access to site that is listed allowed

Tags: cors

I am trying to use json placeholder site to get dummy data for react project. I fetch the data with axios package. I opened my application in Firefox and it showed this error in console:
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘https://localhost:3000’)`.

Then, I inspected the response header and it has the following `CORS` headers:
[image: CORS_HEADER]

according to my understanding if `access-control-allow-credentials` is `true` and `access-control-allow-origin` matched my origin (which is `http://localhost:3000`) then i should be able to access response data but Firefox is blocking it.

What i didn't understand is why Firefox is blocking response data despite `access-control-allow-origin` matches origin. I have also tested this application in Brave browser and it worked fine.

I am using `Firefox developer version 95.0b6 (64-bit)`

Comment: `https://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3000` are different origins (because their schemes are different).

Comment: yes. Thats correct but in response header there is `http://localhost:3000` so it should allow me right.

Comment: The CORS error message suggest that the request was issued by `https://localhost:3000`, though.

Comment: i found the actual problem. The actual problem was due to the `https everywhere` extension. It some how managed to convince firefox that i am using `https` which i wasn't so `CORS` blocked the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, you are doing `localhost` development over `http`, and attempting to use cloudflare via an `https` request (unless I read that wrong). All modern browsers will block this today, because they won't allow cross protocol requests (and I think they no longer allow unsecure requests as well). If you setup your local development environment to run under it's own self signed secure cert, then you can get your CORS calls working with local development.

Comment: yes it was due to the cross protocol request but it wasn't blocked by the browser. Actually, this error was caused due to `https everywhere` extension. I Think the `https everywhere` extension somehow managed to convince browser that i am using `https` protocol without changing http to https in the URL. Since, i was on `http` and allow-origin was also on `http` browser blocked that request.